# Expected ';' after top level declarator in googelAnalytics sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios5.1

I am doing one application.In that i ma using the GoogleAnalytics SDK.It's working in io6,but getting this error in ios5 only at the below line

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger, GAILogLevel){

}
```

How to clear this error in ios 5.

Comment: How about adding a semicolon after that...

Comment: Agreed.  It should fail everywhere, not just under iOS 5.

Comment: No.In ios 6 it's working without error

Comment: @user3146380 Why don't you make a simple experiment. New project > paste it > compile... In fact the compiler would produce 2 errors for this snippet (`Use of empty enum`, `expected ';' after enum`)...

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work with a few adjustments. `typedef` is a statement, so it has to be semicolon terminated.

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger, GAILogLevel){
    // put something in here so it's not an empty enum
};
```